# How to create multiple instance with `redux` based component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using `Redux` with my reactjs app. I strucking with 2 doubts here.

1. I would like to create multiple instace of `redux` based component
2. I like to control / show the store data to other component too..

how to achieve the both? any one help me?

I tried like this: got error:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import App from "./App";
import Source from "./Source"; //how to get store data here too..
import "./styles.css";

var store = createStore(reducer);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("container");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    <App /> //throws error
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jj982r8rvw)

Comment: You forgot to include the error message in your question.

Comment: Do you want the counters to work independently, or do you want them to have the same value when you press one?

Comment: @bwalshy - I like to share the store for multiple component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Provider tag should contain a single React child element. You can overcome this by creating a fake Higher-Order-Component as below:

```
const Aux = props => props.children;
```

Please try the below code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import App from "./App";
import Source from "./Source";
import "./styles.css";

var store = createStore(reducer);
const Aux = props => props.children;
const rootElement = document.getElementById("container");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Aux>
      <App />
      <App />
    </Aux>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: `const Aux = props => props.children;` how this function called? can you explain me little bit? especially how the `props` passes there..? still I am keeping 2 instance both are working on same time on click..

Comment: can you please go through this link? https://github.com/gajus/react-aux

Answer (score 0):

You must connect your  component at Redux Store like this:

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Source extends Component {
  render() {
    const { counter, increaseCount, decreaseCount } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>How to show count here?</h1>
        <h2>{counter}</h2>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            increaseCount();
          }}
        >
          How to increase count?
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  counter: state.count
});

var increaseAction = { type: "increase" };
var decreaseAction = { type: "decrease" };

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    increaseCount: function() {
      return dispatch(increaseAction);
    },
    decreaseCount: function() {
      return dispatch(decreaseAction);
    }
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Source);
```